# iPhone application to show nearby business offices into table view

Tags: iphone

I want to make iPhone application that use GPS to show nearby places (particular business offices) into table view starting nearest office at top of the table.
Location coordinates will come using location manager but i want my application do above tasks

Any suggestion how to implement all these things or any tutorial.
Thank you in advance i really appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 0):

Search the SDK documentation either from XCode or developer.apple.com and you'll find a bunch of white papers and samples relating to your questions.

Edited  to include samples...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Locations/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008406

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html

All found with a simple search in the apple developer website, can't imagine what else you might need at this stage.

Comment: i have searched a lot. i really appriciate if you will suggest me some links. Cheers!

Comment: **i have searched a lot. i really appriciate if you will suggest me some links. Cheers!**